# java's path still /usr/bin/java after brew cask install java

Tags: java, path, installation, homebrew

I installed java with homebrew, using the command brew cask install java.

After successfully installing, I typed which java, and the path showed to be /usr/bin/java

When I typed brew cask info java, this showed up:

> java: 1.8.0_102-b14 Java Standard Edition Development Kit
>
> /usr/local/Caskroom/java/1.8.0_102-b14 (227.5M)
>   https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/blob/master/Casks/java.rb
>   Contents   JDK 8 Update 102.pkg (pkg) Caveats This Cask makes minor
>   modifications to the JRE to prevent issues with packaged applications,
>   as discussed here: If your Java application still asks for JRE
>   installation, you might need to reboot or logout/login.
>
> Installing this Cask means you have AGREED to the Oracle Binary Code
>   License Agreement for Java SE at

Did I forget to link something?

Comment: I have java 1.8.0_102 installed from brew cask, and if I do `which java` I also get `/usr/bin/java`. So that’s not an indication of a problem. `/usr/bin/java` is just a symlink to `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java` which I guess is some indirection thing that finds the right java binary. Anyway, what do you actually get if you run `java -version`? In my environment, even though `which java` gives me `/usr/bin/java`, `java -version` gives me `java version "1.8.0_102" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_102-b14)` (the cask version) as expected.

Comment: I get this:java version "1.8.0_102"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_102-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.102-b14, mixed mode)

Comment: So that’s what you want to see, right? Since that means when you just type `java` it’s using the version you installed from homebrew—and it means the fact that `which java` tells you `/usr/bin/java` is not a problem (in fact that’s expected). In other words, you already have everything working as it should be, and there’s nothing more you need to do (e.g., you don’t need to link anything more).

Comment: https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-install-java-on-mac-osx/

Comment: What exactly is the question here?  "Did I forget to link something", in order to do what?  If you didn't intend to link something, sounds like you didn't forget anything :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`/usr/bin/java` is a symlink.

To see where it points, type `ls -la /usr/bin/java`

brew cask is installing into `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_something.jdk/Contents/Home`

If the previous command `ls -la` is matching this, you are good.

If not, it means that you previously had another java installation. In this case, you may want to use a tool like [jenv](http://www.jenv.be/) to switch between your multiple installs.

Comment: This isn't always true.     brew install. (without cask)  wont do that

Comment: run `brew --prefix java`, so you can find the correct java location.

In my case, using wsl, java has this location:
`/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/openjdk`

Answer (score 5):

To add to @djangofan .. when I did a brew reinstall, I noticed the following message:

```
==> Pouring openjdk--17.0.1_1.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
For the system Java wrappers to find this JDK, symlink it with

  sudo ln -sfn /usr/local/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk

openjdk is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into
/usr/local, because macOS provides similar software and
installing this software in parallel can cause all kinds of
trouble.

If you need to have openjdk first in your PATH, run:
 echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openjdk/bin:$PATH"' >> /Users/johndoe/.bash_profile

For compilers to find openjdk you may need to set:
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openjdk/include"
```

To his point, I did not install via cask. I assume that when you did the install you got a similar message that you simply did not notice.

Comment: I went too fast while installing and missed those messages. Thanks for posting!

Comment: If you need to see this message again, just it the following line in your Terminal: 
`brew info java`

The important bit there is the following:
`echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openjdk/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`
That will make sure you use the latest brewed java version every time you open a new Terminal from now (in my example, I use zsh so in `.zshrc`file it goes)