# java_home is not read by hadoop

Tags: java, macos, hadoop, java-home

I installed java8 with `brew install --cask adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8` but i think i messed things up,

when i type `echo $JAVA_HOME` it gives `/usr/bin/java`

when i type `java -version` it gives `java version "1.8.0_311" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_311-b11) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.311-b11, mixed mode)`

when i type `/usr/libexec/java_home` it gives `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home`

when i try to run hadoop everything starts except namenode.

when i type `namenode -format` after start-all.sh it gives this error:

> ERROR: JAVA_HOME /usr/local/opt/openjdk does not exist.

[My hadoop-env.sh in /etc/hadoop/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1toRE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ensure you JAVA_HOME is set in `/etc/hadoop/conf/hadoop-env.sh`.

in you `~/.bash_profile` add the following:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$<your java install path>
```

check this post on actual install path of Java when using brew:
[java's path still /usr/bin/java after brew cask install java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38921362/javas-path-still-usr-bin-java-after-brew-cask-install-java)

do this in `hadoop-env.sh` :

```
JAVA_HOME=<your java install path>
export JAVA_HOME
```

Comment: can also refer to this post for further insight: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14325594/working-with-hadoop-localhost-error-java-home-is-not-set

Comment: It is already set in hadoop-en.sh

Comment: did you export JAVA_HOME in `bash_profile` ?

Comment: yes i did and then executed source ~/.bash_profile

Comment: @nadazayed On macOS, it should be `~/.profile`, since the default shell can be ZSH

Comment: to check your default shell: go to `Terminal > preference > profiles > shell` and check `run command` field

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thank you so much it worked.